# How to bind list view to multiple entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, listview, entity-framework-6

I want to Bind Listview to multiple entities so i try to do something like that but I face two problems :

1. I lose autocomplete feature ,can't benefit from control strongly
   typed .
2. Get Compile error .

---

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lv_EmpSpecialVacations" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="RelationContainer" ItemType="Repositories.EmployeeSpecialHolidayRepository.AllIncluding(a=>a.SPECIALHOLIDAY).Where(a=>a.EMP_NUM == EmployeeNum);">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <fieldset id="FieldSet1">
            <legend>Relations</legend>
            <br />
            <a id="lbtnInitInsert" class="btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr" onclick="EditForInsert(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        END_DATE
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        HOLIDAY_NAME
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="RelationContainer" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </fieldset>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="toappend">
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 code">

                    <%#:Item.Select(a=>a.END_DATE)>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 name">
                    <%#:Item.Select(a=>a.SPECIALHOLIDAY.HOLIDAY_NAME)%>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <a id="lbtn_edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md white_cr" onclick="Edit(this);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

---

I want to know how to bind `ListView` to Multiple entities without losing the [strongly-typed binding](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-strongly-typed-data-controls)?

Comment: How do you mean "multiple entities" ? Multiple types or multiple instances of the same type?

Comment: @Dexion I mean multiple entities like :`SPECIALHOLIDAY` And `EMPSPECIALHOLIDAY` two different entities with a relationship

Comment: easiest way is to create an "union" with for example two public properties (specialholiday and empspecialholiday) and use them for binding.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to create an "union" with for example two public properties (specialholiday and empspecialholiday) and use them for binding.

Answer (score 1):

There will one relationship in `SPECIALHOLIDAY` and `EMPSPECIALHOLIDAY` like `Holidayname` so by calling it in union or in inner join it will work for u Like this example

**Union example:**

```
SELECT Holidayname FROM SPECIALHOLIDAY
UNION
SELECT Holidayname FROM EMPSPECIALHOLIDAY
ORDER BY Holidayname
```

**Inner Join Example:**

```
SELECT * from  SPECIALHOLIDAY as SP
inner join EMPSPECIALHOLIDAY as ES
on ES.Holidayname = SP.Holidayname 
ORDER BY Holidayname
```

I think this example may work for you.